Radix Tree vs Multi-level bitmap
The Linux kernel (at least before using XArrays as far as I'm aware, which to my knowledge are wrappers around Radix Trees anyway) uses radix trees in its address_space structs which every file has. This allows a file to efficiently find all the dirty buffers which it has written to for easy flushing.
However, what is the advantage of a Radix Tree over a Multi-level Bitmap in this scenario? They seem so much easier to implement, is there a difference?
